# How to return templates from cache or ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

In my code I try to load templates from cache. If template does not present in cache - load template from server by ajax. When loading is finished, I want to put template to cache and return it. Here is it:

```
var manager = function () {

    return {

        cache: [],
        getTemplate: function (templateId) {

            this.templateId = templateId;

            if (this.cache[this.templateId]) {
                return this.cache[this.templateId];
            }

            return this.loadTemplate();
        },

        loadTemplate: function() {

            var
            self = this;

            $.get('/assets/templates/' + this.templateId + '.html', function (templateHtml) {

                self.cache[self.templateId] = templateHtml;
                return self.getTemplate(self.templateId);
            });
        }
    }
}

var
manager = manager();

$('body').append( manager.getTemplate('template') );
```

I know that my code does not working because ajax request finished after function loadTemplate end. I think code can be fixed with deferred object but don't know how. Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way of achieving your goal:

1. [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (there are a lot of libs/shims). I'll rewrite it to ES6 just for the learning:

   ```
   let manager = function () {

       return {

           cache: [],

           getTemplate(id) {
               let cache = this.cache;

               return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   if (cache[id]) {
                       resolve(cache[id]);
                   } else {
                       this.loadTemplate(id)
                           .then(template => {
                               cache[id] = template;
                               resolve(template);
                           })
                           .fail(reject);
                   }
               });
           },

           loadTemplate(id) {
               return $.get('/assets/templates/' + id + '.html');
           }
       }
   };

   let manager = manager();

   manager.getTemplate('template').then((template) => {
       $('body').append(template);
   });
   ```
2. Callbacks:

   ```
   let manager = function () {

       return {

           cache: [],

           getTemplate(id, cb) {
               let cache = this.cache;

               if (cache[id]) {
                   cb(cache[id]);
               } else {
                   this.loadTemplate(id)
                       .then(template => {
                           cache[id] = template;
                           cb(template);
                       });
               }
           },

           loadTemplate(id) {
               return $.get('/assets/templates/' + id + '.html');
           }
       }
   };

   let manager = manager();

   manager.getTemplate('template', (template) => {
       $('body').append(template);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is what I need!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would do it, supporting all major browsers, and caching the requests too. This way you will only perform 1 request per template. (The other answers only cache the response).

```js
var Manager = function() {

   return {

      cache: [],

      getTemplate(id) {
         var that = this;

         if (that.cache[id] && that.cache[id].then){
            console.log("Promise cache");
            return that.cache[id]; //return promise from cache
         }

         return $.Deferred(function() {
            var def = this;
            
            if (that.cache[id]) {
               console.log("Retrieved from cache!");
               return def.resolve(that.cache[id]); //return cached template
            }

            that.cache[id] = def; //Cache promise
            
            console.log("Retrieving template...");
            that.loadTemplate(id).then(function(template) {
               that.cache[id] = template;
               def.resolve(template)
            }).fail(function() {
               def.reject();
            });

            return that.cache[id]; //return promise
            
         }).promise();

      },

      loadTemplate(id) {
         return $.get('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');
      }
   }
};

var manager = Manager();

manager.getTemplate('template').then(function(template){
   console.log("loaded 1");
});

//This will use the promise from the first call (1 Request only)
manager.getTemplate('template').then(function(template){
    console.log("loaded 2");
    manager.getTemplate('template').then(function(template){
       console.log("loaded 3"); //This will be retrieved fully from cache
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you too:) Now I can to complete my code with all answears

Answer (score 1):

As you are fetching the template via AJAX, you will be able to append the result only in AJAX success. So you need to pass the append logic as callback.Check the below code.

```
var manager = function () {

    return {

        cache: [],
        getTemplate: function (templateId,callback) {

            this.templateId = templateId;

            if (this.cache[this.templateId]) {
                callback(this.cache[this.templateId]);
            }

            this.loadTemplate(callback);
        },

        loadTemplate: function(callback) {

            var
            self = this;

            $.get('/assets/templates/' + this.templateId + '.html', function (templateHtml) {

                self.cache[self.templateId] = templateHtml;
                callback(templateHtml)
            });
        }
    }
}

var
manager = manager();

manager.getTemplate('template',function(result) {

$('body').append( result );
});
```

You may not need 2 functions to do this. So you can make it as one

Comment: Thank you very much for you answear!